# 1993 Ford Tempo: Remove Power Lock Actuator

Tags: ford, locks

I have an 1993 Ford Tempo, and upon examining the lock mechanism (sans disassembly)  we suspect the actuator is the problem. Sadly, I can't seem to get it out.

On all doors, the motor seems to be held in place by some sort of connector.  However, this is not the same across the front doors: the left side door has a plastic cap that goes into the hole; nothing really seems to stick out of the hole.  The right, side, however, has some sort of metallic thing that spins freely.

Is this a rivet?  *Do you want a picture of it (or the motor)?*  Someone at the parts store suggests that the motor is supposed to snap out of the plastic holder (which is what is ACTAULLY connected to this little hole) but it does not seem to.

Thanks in advance.
**EDIT: Pictures** (Meta:someone who knows what they are doing feel free to make them smaller, I'm surprised SE doesn't support that?)

[[image][image]

Comment: Is this the style where the actuator is riveted to the door panel and has a metal rod that comes out and clips to the latch? Pics of both would be helpful.

Comment: @ben Sorry for the delay, but: pictures.

Comment: That is definitely a rivet, and it will need to be drilled out to remove the actuator. Not unusual at all for Fords from that era; to remove the power window actuator on my 1991 Ford Explorer I had to drill a hole in the inside door panel just to access a rivet, that I then had to drill out.

Comment: You can actually pop them out of the bracket....see this video for a mustang on how to do it....https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xWoB7Uhxd9c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a rivet and needs to be drilled out to remove the actuator. Usually a new lock actuator will come with a replacement. If not you’ll need to source the correct size and would need the tool to install it.